# R-squared for glmmTMB with beta distribution and logit link

Tags: r, r-squared, beta-distribution, glmmtmb, logarithm

I'm looking for a method or function for computing R² for glmmTMB models with a beta distribution and a logit link. I am interested in a ratio (%) response in a repeated measures design.

I looked into:

- the `sem.model.fits()` function from the package {piecewiseSEM}
- the `r.squaredGLMM()` function from the package {MuMIn}
- the procedure described by *Shinichi Nakagawa, Paul C. D. Johnson & Holger Schielzeth in “The coefficient of determination R²2
  and intra-class correlation ICC from generalized linear-mixed effects models revisited and expanded” published in September 2017 (DOI: 10.1098/rsif.2017.0213)* or by *Paul C. D. Johnson in "Extension of Nakagawa & Schielzeth's R2GLMM to random slopes models" published in July 2014 ([https://doi.org/10.1111/2041-210X.12225)](https://doi.org/10.1111/2041-210X.12225)_)*.

The procedure described by Shinichi Nakagawa (for glmer models) is the following:

```
mod_ref=FULL MODEL (containing all random and fixed terms)
mod_0= NULL MODEL (containing only random terms)
VarF <- var(as.vector(model.matrix(mod_ref) %*% fixef(mod_ref)))
nuN <- 1/attr(VarCorr(mod_0), "sc")^2 # note that glmer report 1/nu not nu as resiudal variance
VarOdN <- 1/nuN # the delta method
VarOlN <- log(1 + 1/nuN) # log-normal approximation
VarOtN <- trigamma(nuN) # trigamma function
c(VarOdN = VarOdN, VarOlN = VarOlN, VarOtN = VarOtN)
nuF <- 1/attr(VarCorr(mod_ref), "sc")^2 # note that glmer report 1/nu not nu as resiudal variance
VarOdF <- 1/nuF # the delta method
VarOlF <- log(1 + 1/nuF) # log-normal approximation
VarOtF <- trigamma(nuF) # trigamma function
c(VarOdF = VarOdF, VarOlF = VarOlF, VarOtF = VarOtF)
R2glmmM <- VarF/(VarF + sum(as.numeric(VarCorr(mod_ref))) + VarOtF)
R2glmmC <- (VarF + sum(as.numeric(VarCorr(mod_ref))))/(VarF +sum(as.numeric(VarCorr(mod_ref)))+VarOtF)
```

The procedure described by Paul Johnson is the following (mod=full model):

```
X <- model.matrix(mod_ref)
n <- nrow(X)
Beta <- fixef(mod_ref)
Sf <- var(X %*% Beta)
Sigma.list <- VarCorr(mod_ref)
Sl <- 
sum(
  sapply(Sigma.list,
    function(Sigma)
    {
      Z <-X[,rownames(Sigma)]
      sum(diag(Z %*% Sigma %*% t(Z)))/n
    }))
  Se <- attr(Sigma.list, "sc")^2
  Sd <- 0
  total.var <- Sf + Sl + Se + Sd
  (Rsq.m <- Sf / total.var) 
  (Rsq.c <- (Sf + Sl) / total.var)
```

However, I was unable to find this particular combination in any of the above packages or article.

When I try to run these two scripts on my glmmTMB model : `regd=glmmTMB(Ratio~block+treatment*scale(year)+(1|year)+(1|plot)+(1|year:plot),family=list(family="beta",link="logit"),data=biomass)`, I get the following error message: `Error in model.matrix(mod_ref) %*% fixef(mod_ref) : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments` at line 3 of Nakagawa's method and `Error in X %*% Beta : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments` at line 4 of Johnson's method.

When I check model.matrix(mod_ref), it yields the following matrix:
[image]

When I check fixef(mod_ref), I get the following:
[image]

Could this be easily adapted?

A short reproducible example:

```
library(glmmTMB)
set.seed(101)
ngrp <- 100
eps <- 0.001
nobs <- 4000
ngrp <- 200
nobs <- 800
x <- rnorm(nobs)
f <- factor(rep(1:ngrp,nobs/ngrp))
u <- rnorm(ngrp,sd=1)
eta <- 2+x+u[f]
mu <- plogis(eta)
y <- rbeta(nobs,shape1=mu/0.1,shape2=(1-mu)/0.1)
y <- pmin(1-eps,pmax(eps,y))
dd <- data.frame(x,y,f)

mod_ref <- glmmTMB(y~x+(1|f),family=list(family="beta",link="logit"),
          data=dd)
mod_0 <- glmmTMB(y~1+(1|f),family=list(family="beta",link="logit"),
          data=dd)
```

Comment: Is this a mixed model? Or a single level model? If you use the framework of Nakagawa, Schielzeth and Johnson, then it is possible.

Comment: @user162986 I edited the post in a more detailed way because I tried to use the framework for glmmTMB and ended up with some error messages. Maybe you have some idea as to how to adapt this? Thanks for your interest

Comment: That error usually occurs when one of the objects you're multiplying is not a matrix or contains text. Check the result of `model.matrix(mod_ref)` to be sure it is what you think it is.

Comment: @user162986 Thanks again for pushing things a little further. I added the output of model.matrix(mod_ref) and fixef(mod_ref). They seem pretty typical to me but I rarely dig this deep!

Comment: I can't think of what is wrong. I've never had this happen whenever doing this except I had non numbers or was multiplying a data.frame by mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure, doesn't glmmTMB return a list for `VarCorr()`, because it always returns an element for the conditional and the possible zero-inflated model. So you may need `VarCorr()[[1]]` here, but a reprex would make debugging-life easier. :-)

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for you interest. I haven't gotten to VarCorr() because the script bugs at VarF <- var(as.vector(model.matrix(mod_ref) %*% fixef(mod_ref))) (line 3 of Nakagawa's method) and at Sf <- var(X %*% Beta) (line 4 of Johnson's method). I added a short reproducible example :)

Comment: To `fixef()` applies the same, so you probably need to use `fixef()[[1]]`.

Comment: What is the variance of your `mod_ref`? Most families in glmmTMB have a `stats::family(x)$variance` function, however, this does not exist for the beta-family.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if your described code is correct. I've implemented an `r2()`-function for glmmTMB in my _sjstats_ package, based on the code from Ben Bolker (https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/blob/master/glmmTMB/inst/misc/rsqglmm.R). That function does currently not support beta-families (due to the missing of the former mentioned variance-function), but when I run `r2()` with another model (say, poisson), and then use your implementation of the Nakagawa-approach, I get different results.

Comment: The code is a copy paste from the Supplementary material (Appendix S6) but is adapted to glmer models. Nakagawa does not provide examples for glmmTMB models. stats::family(mod_ref)$variance yields NULL. Concerning your discrepancy between r2() and Nakagawa's approach, I found the same thing and decided (for other families) to stick with rsquared.glmerMod() which yields the same as sem.model.fits().

Answer (score 1):

Both the results from `fixef` and `VarCorr` are lists with `$cond` for conditioning variables, `$zi` zero inflation, and `$disp` for the Beta dispersion (parametrized as mean + dispersion). Using `fixef(mod_ref)$cond` and `Sigma.list$cond` gives you no error.